# closing a panel in a nib file hangs the application

Tags: objective-c

I have a panel in my nib file that opens on  clicking menu item in my application
After performing some tasks on the panel , when I close the panel my application hangs .
Please suggest  me the reason for it and any possible solution.
When I used separate nib files for my application and panel  ,things worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

More information needed.  But better yet, some debugging techniques so you can figure it out yourself:

1. hit "pause" in the debugger - where are you?  Look at the backtrace/callchain to see what is going on.
2. Have you looked in the console window for any diagnostic messages?
3. Set a breakpoint on the code that is called when the close action for the panel is activated and then step through the handling and see how far it gets.

that ought to get you started.